# API to fetch last login date jira cloud

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, python-jira

Is there any JIRA REST API which can give information about last login time of all users for jira cloud platform?

If yes, then please provide me the details of the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

it is not available (as of June 2022), they have a request but they are not considering it yet:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/ID-6965

there might be some custom plugins extending the REST API for server but I doubt they would allow such a plugin on the cloud side